# is it possible to handle exception from a single place

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, exception

I have dao, service and action classes in my spring mvc application.
I am throwing Exception in Dao and Service classes. Now in Action, normally I have to write try catch block and in case exception occurs in dao and service, it will be thrown from there and it will go in catch block in action.

I have a error jsp which will be displayed.

Problem is I need to write same catch block in all action methods.

Is it possible to throw it again in action methods too and handle it from a single point rather than writing same code everywhere.

Please suggest.

Comment: Are action classes Spring MVC controllers?

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc might help

Comment: Make your exceptions unchecked (extend `RuntimeException`) and you won't need all these try-catches cluttering up your code (I bet they don't do anything useful in the catch block other than log and/or throw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also have a look at `Spring Integration`. It provides the use of gateways, filters and channels. Each can have a Request, Response and Error channel assigned. Or there is even a default error handler. In case all data flows through a specific channel, having a custom error handler is as simple as follows:

```
@MessageEndpoint
public class MyErrorHandler {
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "errorChannel")
    public String handle(String messsage) {
       // do whatever you like
    }
}
```

The Integration framework offers lots of usefull stuff for general handling.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for cross-cutting exception handling and good news, you are working with **Spring MVC** yes you can use this feature.

All you need to do, is throw your `CustomExcptions` or whatever other `Exceptions` that are from your *services* to your *action* methods.

Let's say here is your service:

```
@Service
public class MyService {
  public void someMethod throws RuntimeException {
  ...
  }
}
```

In your controller method:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {
  @Autowired
  MyService service;

  @RequestMapping("/someuri"){
    try {
      service.someMethod();
    } catch {
      throw new RuntimeException();
    }
  }

  @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
  public ModelAndView handleException(RuntimeException ex) {
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView("errorpage");
    return model;
  }
}
```

The `handleException` method annotated with `ExceptionHandler` is your advice method for exception handling and it will be called anytime a `RuntimeException` is throw inside your controller and you can keep up like this for all other exceptions.